# How do I stop PHP from making a Zip File?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

OK, If you need me to post any more of my code I have come up with then let me know. I am not sure this is even possible. But what I want to do is stop PHP from making a Zip file when the user selects a cancel button / link.

Now what I have set up is all the files upload per user are listed in a form, the user then can selected which files they wish to zip and download. Once the files are selected and the download button clicked, the div holding the form is changed via a Jquery AJAX call, which works fine no issues.

But I have a 'Cancel' / 'Stop' button / link which sort of works. Once clicked I call the .abort on the AJAX request and then loads new HTML content saying the user cancelled the zip making progress. However, all the message works fine, it seems like the server is still making the zip in the background and any links will not respond (most are also AJAX requests to load in new users requests) until the zip has been made.

The base of my site is using the CakePHP framework. But I am sure this is just standard Jquery / PHP issue.

Any ideas on how to get my AJAX request to stop PHP from making the zip?

This is how I am building my AJAX :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".MAKEMYZIP").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      $('.DIV-HOLDER').load('/PAGE-PREVIEWER');
      var MakeNewZipFile = $.ajax({
        url: '/makezip',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'html',   //expect return data as html from server
        data: $('.FILE_DATA').serialize(),
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          $('.DIV-HOLDER').html(response);   //select the id and put the response in the html
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log('error(s):'+textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      }); //End of AJAX call 
             //Below line makes the 'text' link visible once the make zip but clicked.
    $('.ZipLinkHolder').css("visibility","visible");
    $( ".Can_Zip_This_Zip" ).click(function() {
        MakeNewZipFile.abort();
        $('.DIV-HOLDER').html('<br/><br/><div class="CenterTxt">User has canceled Zip making process.</div>');
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Why not when a use clicks abort, run some PHP code to delete the file?

Comment: Can I unlink the file using AJAX? The file has not been complete when the user clicks on the abort link

Comment: Not sure how you are naming the files, maybe the safest way to do this is a CRON job

Comment: @david-nguyen - my files names are timestamp + filename - I have never used a CRON job within CakePHP before but I look into that! But can I get a CRON job to run after or when the user selects the cancel link?

Comment: @GlennCurtis CRON jobs run automatically for time intervals, for example remove files that are 1 day old once a day. Another thing you could do is pass back the file name from the first call, and on the cancel call pass the file name back. BUT there are some obvious security issues here as people could pass malicious variables back to you. If you go that route maybe just pass the timestamp back and fourth and cleanse the abort data.